# Craft 2 new locale and dealing with root-relative links

Tags: localization, craft2

Hi I am adding new locale which is jp and I have a huge problem with href tag.
Our paragraph field have href links using relative link like this:

```
<a href="/page_a"> page a</a>
```

When I hover to the link. It show "example.com/page_a" instead of "example.com/jp/page_a".
Our siteUrl was set up correctly which is shows example.com/jp.
Is anyone face this issue before and how to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `{{ url('/page_a') }}`, this should generate the correct url.